# How could I manage the App Engine Go runtime context to avoid App Engine lock-in?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm writing a Go application to run on App Engine's Go runtime.

I notice that pretty much any operation which uses an App Engine service (such as Datastore, Mail, or even Capabilities) requires that you pass it an instance of `appengine.Context` which must be retrieved using the function `appengine.NewContext(req *http.Request) Context`.

While I am writing this app for App Engine, I want to be able to move it to some other platform (possibly one which doesn't support any of the App Engine API) easily and quickly if I should so choose.

So, I'm abstracting away the actual interaction with App Engine services and API's by writing little wrappers around any App-Engine-specific interaction (including request handling functions).  With this approach, if I ever do wish to move to a different platform, I'll just rewrite those specific modules which tie my application to App Engine.  Easy and straightforward.

The only problem is that `appengine.Context` object.  I can't pass it down from my request handlers through my layers of logic to the modules which handle these API's without tying pretty much all of my code to App Engine.  I could pass the `http.Request` object from which the `appengine.Context` object can be derived, but that would require coupling things that probably shouldn't be coupled.  (I think it's best practice for none of my application to even know it's a web application except those portions specifically dedicated to handling HTTP requests.)

The first solution that sprang to mind was to just create a persistent variable in some module.  Something like this:

```
package context

import (
    "appengine"
)

var Context appengine.Context
```

Then, in my request handlers, I can set that variable with `context.Context = appengine.NewContext(r)` and in the modules that directly use App Engine services, I can fetch the context by accesing `context.Context`.  None of the intervening code would need to know of the `appengine.Context` object's existence.  The only problem is that ["multiple requests may be handled concurrently by a given instance"](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/overview), which can lead to race conditions and unexpected behavior with this plan.  (One request sets it, another sets it, the first one accesses it and gets the wrong `appengine.Context` object.)

I could in theory store the `appengine.Context` to datastore, but then I'd have to pass some request-specific identifier down the logic layers to the service-specific modules identifying which `appengine.Context` object in datastore is the one for the current request, which would again couple things I don't think should be coupled.  (And, it would increase my application's datastore usage.)

I could also pass the `appengine.Context` object down the whole logic chain with the type `interface{}` the whole way and have any module which doesn't need the `appengine.Context` object ignore it.  That would avoid tying most of my application to anything *specific*.  That also seems highly messy, however.

So, I'm at a bit of a loss how to cleanly ensure the App-Engine-specific modules which need the `appengine.Context` object can get it.  Hopefully you folks can give me a solution I have yet to think of myself.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is tricky because your self-imposed scoping rule (which is a sensible one) means not passing a `Context` instance around, and there is nothing similar to Java's `ThreadLocal` to achieve the same ends by sneaky means. That's actually a Good Thing, really.

`Context` combines logging support (easy) with a `Call` to appengine services (not easy). There are I think ten appengine functions that need a `Context`. I can't see any clean solution other than wrapping all of these behind your own facade.

There is one thing that can help you - you can include a configuration file with your app that indicates whether it's in GAE or otherwise, using a flag of some sort. Your global boolean need only store this flag (*not* a shared context). Your facade functions can then consult this flag when deciding whether to use `NewContext(r)` to obtain the `Context` to access GAE services, or use a lookalike structure to access your own substitute services.

Edit: As a final remark, when you solve this may I invite you to share how you did it, possibly even with an open-source project? Cheeky of me to ask, but if you don't ask... ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your response!  I think I have an idea that may work for my particular application.  I'm not sure it would work in general, but might work for some significant percentage of App Engine apps.  If my idea ends up being a semi-general solution, I'll definitely release it as an open source project.  :D

Comment: Most of my application has access to either a user id or a session id.  My plan is just to create a persistent map keyed on values derived directly from either a session id or a user id.  The request handlers can create and store the context objects and the modules that need a context can retrieve them similarly.  I'm not completely sure it will work out, though.  (There may be some modules which don't have access to a session id or user id.  I might have to get creative in some of those cases.)

Answer (score 7):

I (hopefully) solved this issue by wrapping my request handlers (in this example one called "realHandler") like this:

```
http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ds := NewDataStore(r)
    realHandler(w, r, ds)
})
```

NewDataStore creates a DataStore, which is a simple wrapper that abstracts the GAE datastore. It has an unexposed field where it stores the context:

```
type DataStore struct {
    c appengine.Context
}

func NewDataStore(req *http.Request) *DataStore {
    return &DataStore{appengine.NewContext(req)}
}
```

Within the request handler, I can just access the abstracted datastore when I need it without worrying about the GAE context, which has already been set:

```
func realHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request, db *DataStore) {
    var s SomeStruct{}
    key, err := db.Add("Structs", &s)
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Particularly in case of Datastore you should be able to reuse the same `appengine.Context` among different requsts. I haven't tried to do it myself but that's the way an alternative API for Datastore called [goon](http://godoc.org/github.com/mjibson/goon) works:

> Goon differs from the datastore package in various ways: it remembers the appengine Context, which need only be specified once at creation time

The fact that storage should depend on HTTP request sounds ridiculous by the way. I don't think Datastore depends on a *particular* request in the usual sense. Most probably, it's needed to identify a particular Google App Engine application which obviously stays the same from request to request. My speculations are based on quick skim over the [source code](https://github.com/golang/appengine) of `google.golang.org/appengine`.

You may do similar observations in regard of the other Google App Engine APIs. Of cause all the details *could be* implementation specific and I'd performed more deep research before actually using those observations in a real application.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth to note that Go team introduced a [golang.org/x/net/context](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/context) package.

Later on the context was made available in Managed VMs, the repo is [here](https://github.com/golang/appengine). The documentation states:

> This repository supports the Go runtime on App Engine, including both classic App Engine and Managed VMs. It provides APIs for interacting with App Engine services. Its canonical import path is `google.golang.org/appengine`.

What it means is that you could easily write another packages out of dev environment depending on `appengine`.

In particular it becomes very easy to wrap around packages like `appengine/log` (trivial log wrapper [example](https://github.com/orian/utils/tree/master/net/log)).

But even more important this allows one to create handlers in a form:

`func CoolHandler(context.Context, http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)`

There's an article about a `context` package on Go blog [here](https://blog.golang.org/context). I wrote about using context [here](http://dev.pawelsz.eu/2015/10/save-yourself-and-pass-context-by.html). If you decide to use the handler with context passing around it's good to create context for all requrests in one place. You can do it by using non standard requrest router like [github.com/orian/wctx](https://github.com/orian/wctx).

Answer (score 0):

I handled this by wrapping `appengine.NewContext` behind an interface, and provide different implementations through different packages. That way, I don't have to link GAE into any binaries where it isn't used:

```
type Context interface {
  GetHTTPContext(r *http.Request) context.Context
}
```

I provide a method for subpackages to register themselves when imported for side effects, sort of `database/sql`-style:

```
var _context Context
func Register(c Context) {
  _context = c // Nil checking, double registration checking omitted for brevity
}
```

I start with a default implementation for vanilla, non-GAE binaries, that simply grabs the existing context:

```
var _context Context = &defaultContext{} // use this by default
type defaultContext struct {}
func (d *defaultContext) GetHTTPContext(r *http.Request) context.Context {
  return r.Context()
}
```

Then I put an App Engine implementation in a package `mything/context/appengine`:

```
import(
  ctx "mything/context"
)

type aecontext struct {}
func (a *aecontext) GetHTTPContext(r *http.Request) context.Context {
  return appengine.NewContext(r)
}

func init() {
  ctx.Register(&aecontext{})
}
```

Then my GAE binary can pull in the subpackage, which registers itself in `init`:

```
import(
  _ "mything/context/appengine"
)
```

And my app code uses `GetHTTPContext(r)` to get an appropriate context to pass into dependencies.